# How to bring key pad in windows phone to normal/standard state programatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 application (chat application). I have a text box for typing messages. When I type a message(and press send), which ends with something like a question mark or exclamatory mark, I need the keypad to show alphabets instead of showing the symbols which I last used. How can I achieve this? 
Tell me if I need to post anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do, is put "Chat"-input scope to your textbox.

```
<TextBox InputScope="Chat" />
```

If you then press enter, it will change from symbols to the alphabets.

If your sending works with button, then you have to focus to the textbox in send-button's tap event.

Comment: I am setting InputScope = "Chat" in the xaml. My text bar does not lose focus when I send the message, so the key pad does not close.

Comment: That's weird.. Do you use button to send the message? Of course you can set focus to the current page, and then immediately back to text box. It should fix the problem, but not nice solution anyway :/

Comment: I have a button in ApplicationBar and am sending the message on this button's click event. So my text box is not losing focus. I thought of doing that  (setting focus to current page and go back to text box) but decided against it. Can I change the inputscope of the key pad without it losing focus?

Comment: Yes you could http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521152(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_SettingtheKeyboardInputScopeinCode but problem is that alphabetics and symbols belongs to the same input scope. It might be easiest to change the focus to page and back...

Comment: Changing the foucs to page and back is also not working.

Comment: Hmm.. how it doesn't work? I made also a simple application with textBox and applicationBarIconButton, and it worked. In button's click event I call first Focus(), and then MyTextBox.Focus().

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
InputScope isScope1 = new InputScope();
InputScopeName isScopeNumber = new InputScopeName();
isScopeNumber.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Number;
isScope1.Names.Add(isScopeNumber);

textBox2.InputScope = isScope1;

InputScope isScope = new InputScope();
InputScopeName isScopeName = new InputScopeName();
isScopeName.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.EmailUserName;
isScope.Names.Add(isScopeName);

textBox3.InputScope = isScope;

}
}
```

Best reference for this would be:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Hope it helps!